# syslog Log/ Event generator linux

Tags: linux, events, logging, generator, syslog

I am looking for a syslog event/log generator for RHEL 5. Do you know any? 
It will be used for security simulations. I have a programme, which gives me possibility to monitor the events from a remote client and this generator can help me a lot.

Thanks in advance,

Marcin

Comment: `syslog` is normally default in these systems.

Answer (score 4):

The LogZilla project has one available for free (for personal use). You can grab it from the Subversion server at https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/logzilla/scripts/contrib/sysloggen

To check it out in Linux:

svn co https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/logzilla/scripts/contrib/sysloggen

To get help, type './sysloggen -h':

```
LogZilla(tm) Syslog Generation Tool v1.0
This tool is free for personal (home) use only.
Please contact sales@logzilla.pro for permission to use elsewhere.

Usage: sysloggen --dest <target1[:port]> [-d <target2[:port]>, ... ] --file <raw_messages_file> [Options]

Options:
  -d <ip/unix_socket>, --dest <ip/unix_socket>
     IP address or Unix Domain socket name (when used together with the --unix option)
  -f <raw_messages_file>, --file <raw_messages_file>
      File name, file should contain preformatted syslog messages
  -s, --file_source <ip>   Spoof file_source IP address using UDP transport  -i, --inet   Use the TCP (by default) or UDP (when used together with the --dgram option)
  -u, --unix   Use a UNIX domain socket to send the messages to the target
  -S, --stream Use a stream socket (TCP or unix-stream) to send the messages to the target
  -D, --dgram  Use datagram socket (UDP or unix-dgram) to send the messages to the target
  -r, <messages/second>, --rate <messages/second>
      The number of messages generated per second, otherwise - max possible
  -n <messages>, --number <messages>
      Limit the number of messages to be sent
  -l, --loop   Read the file specified in --file options in loop
  -m <size>, --max-msg-size <size> Messages will be truncated if bigger then <size>
  -h, --help   Print this message and exit
  -v, --verbose    Make verbose output

Example:
Send 1 Million syslog events (loaded from the file "sample_cisco_ios.syslog") to 192.168.1.1 on TCP Port 514 at a rate of 20k events/sec
./sysloggen -d 192.168.1.1:514 -f sample_cisco_ios.syslog -n 1000000 -r 20000 -l
```

Comment: Do you know any libc.so.6 (GLIBC-2.14) source for LogZilla cause nothing is passing to my RedHat 5?

Comment: Are you x_86 or x_64? I can compile it for you

Comment: You can find it at https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/logzilla//scripts/contrib/sysloggen/CentOS6.4_x64 - I compiled it on CentOS 64, but also tested it on RHEL 5.9 and it works.

Comment: Hi Marcin, please mark the question as answered